# using zend framework with the existing apache server that is without using zend server

Tags: zend-framework

I want to learn zend framework.

I followed a tutorial which showed a folder structure and i created like that with index.php in web_root folder.

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Zend-Framework-Intro-Creating-Controller-P474.html

I have copied the Zend folder into the library folder of my application as mentioned in the tutorial. i downloaded the minimal version of zend.

Here is my folder structure

[image]

in the htaccess the redirection is set to index.php

**Do i have to use zend server to run this app?**

**Can i use the apache which comes with xampp bundle?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do i have to use zend server to run this app?

No.

> Can i use the apache which comes with xampp bundle?

Yes.

See https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=setup+xampp+zend+framework

Answer (score 1):

No you do not have to use zend server to use zend framework, you can run your application using apache web server.